# Subspaces and Dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v$ be a non-zero vector in $\Bbb R^n$, and let $W = \{ x \in \Bbb R^n | v^T x = 0\}$. Show that $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ of dimension $(n-1)$.

I was able to prove that $W$ is a subspace. However, I have absolutely no idea how to prove that $W$ is $(n-1)$ dimensional. Please help!! Thanks.

Comment: Try to apply rank-nullity theorem to $f(x) = v^Tx$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Define a map $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $ such that $T (x)=v^Tx, x\in \Bbb R^n$. First prove that $T $ is a linear transformation. Note that $\dim (\text {image}(T))=1$. Also observe that $\ker (T)=W $. Now use rank-nullity theorem.